# Is there a better way to pass these instances and variables through each other?

Tags: python, python-re

Python and coding newbie and I'm learning about classes. This is the most complex thing I've coded yet, and I honestly hardly understand why this all works. I know there are probably better ways to perform the search and return the info, but I did it this way for the sake of experimenting and learning.

I'm mostly concerned with my usage of the class and self variables. If willing, I'd greatly appreciate advice on how to clean this up, as classes are still new territory for me. I'll be moving deeper and getting more complex with this code, so I would love the help! Proud of myself for even figuring out how to make this work, so now I've got to ensure I'm doing it properly :)

```
import re

baby_str = """<tr align="right"><td>1</td><td>Michael</td><td>Jessica</td>
<tr align="right"><td>2</td><td>Christopher</td><td>Ashley</td>
<tr align="right"><td>3</td><td>Matthew</td><td>Brittany</td>
<tr align="right"><td>4</td><td>Joshua</td><td>Amanda</td>
<tr align="right"><td>5</td><td>Daniel</td><td>Samantha</td>"""


class main():
    first_search = r'<tr align="right"><td>1'
    def __init__(self, pat=first_search, text=baby_str):
        self.ranking = 1
        self.pat = pat
        self.text = text

    def rank_numbers(self, pat=first_search, text=baby_str):
        match = re.search(pat, text)
        search_base = r'<tr align="right"><td>'
        if match:
            self.ranking += 1
            second_search = search_base + str(self.ranking)
            print(match.group().lstrip(search_base))
            self.rank_numbers(pat=second_search, text=baby_str)
        else:
            pass


def extract_names():
    print("Baby Names Rankings")
    search = main()
    search.rank_numbers()


extract_names()
```

Comment: It is prefered to use ``Beautifulsoup`` for parsing rather than regex, which makes it easy when parsing complex html.

Comment: Yes, I know :) I'm just practicing re with html code haha

Comment: What will the expected output look like ?

Comment: Expected output will continue to parse each line and just be "1 - Michael - Jessica", "2 - Christopher - Ashley" etc

Comment: I think whether or not the code is in proper shape might depend a lot on how complex it gets and in which direction you want to continue. The recursive calling of `rank_numbers` seems a bit overly complicated because the iteration is just over integers incremented by 1. You could use a `while match` loop there, maybe. As you are just practicing, I personally would think that one would not set a default value for `text` in `__init__` in a realistic scenario.

Comment: The while loop makes the most sense for what I was trying to do here, thanks. For your comment on not setting a default value for text, could you please suggest how to do it differently? Getting the script to run properly without setting the default values is exactly what I was trying to figure out here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it helped me tackle the problem and understand how all of this works! I've got classes down now :)

Answer (score 0):

`rank_numbers` function can be re-written as below,

```
def rank_numbers():
    for s in baby_str.splitlines():
        print(" - ".join(re.findall("<td>(\w+)<\/td>", s)))
```

---

```
1 - Michael - Jessica
2 - Christopher - Ashley
3 - Matthew - Brittany
4 - Joshua - Amanda
5 - Daniel - Samantha
```

Answer (score 0):

For the heck of it.. Here is my -overly complicated- solution that I was stubbornly determined to figure out how to do without the 'proper' way described above.

```
with open(path, 'r') as file:
    base = r'<tr align="right"><td>'
    count = 1
    for line in file.readlines():
        search = base + str(count)
        match = re.search(search, line)
        if match:
            print(match.group().lstrip(base))
            count += 1
```